# Draw B-tree vertically

Tags: graphviz, spline, dot

[Is there a way to draw B-Trees on Graphviz?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19985946) suggests alternating *link, data, link, data, link, ...* However, I have, potentially, lots of data in a node such that I can't really space it out horizontally. I am using a vertical node with the arrows from one corner to simulate having the arrows between data.

```
digraph {
    graph [rankdir=LR, truecolor=true, bgcolor=transparent];
    node [shape=none];
    node1 [label = <
<table>
    <tr><td port="0">Ugargeeon</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="1">103</td></tr>
</table>>];
    node1:0:se -> node2;
    node1:1:se -> node3;
    node2 [label = <
<table>
    <tr><td>Rutorshar</td></tr>
    <tr><td>17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>69</td></tr>
</table>>];
    node3 [label = <
<table>
    <tr><td>Nashmokum</td></tr>
    <tr><td>117</td></tr>
    <tr><td>135</td></tr>
</table>>];
}
```

Gives.

[image: The result of the digraph.][image: Desired.]

The first image is pretty close to what I want as the initial starting point, except, the initial spline is pointing to the south-east. The second image I've edited to show what I think the ideal output should be. That is, roughly symmetrical. Globally setting `splines=line` works, but with more edges, it becomes easier to tell them apart when they are the default splines. Is there a way to position the arrows between the nodes *without* affecting the initial spline state?

Comment: 1. Could you rephrase your goal, or maybe show us a sketch of what change you want. 2. Do you want splined edges, straight-line edges, other?

Comment: @sroush I have `splines=false` currently, but I really could use the splines; I've updated the question, thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't fight with graphviz for arrow shapes. You will add a lot of dummy elements to make them perfect, and then adding another node will break it again. Now you have not ideal arrows _and_ a lot of junk in your diagram code. You can add `shape=plain` for node2 and node3 to make arrows hit the tables directly. And add `:w` to the right part of the edge definition to make arrows hit the tables in the middle. But that's about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close?  Major change is to use ports on the head end of the edge - either to West side of entire node or a specific cell.  Pick your spline type, Also twiddled with drawing the table, strictly aesthetic.

```
//  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72428350/draw-b-tree-vertically
digraph {
    graph [rankdir=LR, truecolor=true, bgcolor=transparent];
    splines=false // made a guess, should work fine true or false
    node [shape=none];
    node1 [label = <
<table>
    <tr><td port="p0">Ugargeeon</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="p1">103</td></tr>
</table>>];

    node1:p0:se -> node2:w;
    //node1:p1:se -> node3:w;  // does not actually touch the node
    node1:p1:se -> node3:p1:w; // looks a bit better?
    
    node2 [label = <
<table>
    <tr><td port="p0">Rutorshar</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="p1">17</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="p2">69</td></tr>
</table>>];

    node3 [label = <
<table BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr><td port="p0">Nashmokum</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="p1">117</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="p2">135</td></tr>
</table>>];
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks a little better. Setting `splines=false` is really the thing that makes the most difference, which is not that bad. Not ideal, but better. (And yes, the default tables are pretty awful.)